# Moved files in project and now I can't find namespaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I previously had all of my source files in the same folder just scattered about, but I was getting tired of the disorder, so I created a folder hierarchy and organized my headers and .cpp files in those folders, and changed the `ClInclude` tags in the projects .vcxproj file accordingly. I then changed all the #include rows in the source headers to match the new location of the headers.

Now when I compile I get a heap of errors saying that the namespace "math" can't be found. The namespace could be found before the file organizing, so the problem should be something with that, but that `#include`s works fine.

If I write

```
using namespace
```

the autocomplete finds the namespace just fine, and no red wiggly lines show up in the text interface.

I'm using VS17 Community.

Comment: This usually happens due to abuse of "using namespace". New C++ developers will do themselves a favor if they completely forget that this exists in C++, and always use fully-qualified namespace references. This will avoid hard to track down compilation failures, and bugs of this nature. Because of that, unfortunately, nobody will be able to help you without a [mcve], since the problem is specific to the actual code you're trying to compile.

Comment: I only use "using namespace" in the main method. I only included it as extra information. I write "math::..." everywhere that isn't the main method.

Comment: Again, without a [mcve], it won't be possible to help you. A general description of what you think your code consists of is not really a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two ways to resolve your issue. You've already noted the first, that you can always use relative paths (relative to the source file).

```
#include "..\Math\math.h"
```

This will work just fine. You can *also* modify your C++ Project Properties to add a list of include directories. This will be very useful for you when you begin working on projects that use a *lot* of libraries To add include directories you need to:

1. **right-click** on your project in the solution explorer and select **Properties.**
2. In the left pane, click on the **C/C++ > General** tab.
3. On the property that says **Additional Include Directories**, click the drop down arrow (you may need to click inside the text first) and select **Edit...**

From here, you can add a list of include directories that you will be using with your project. You can use:

### Absolute Paths

`C:\Path\to\Math`

### Relative Paths (relative to your .vcxproj file)

`..\..\relative\path\to\Math`

### Macros (Visual Studio will list your available macros)

`($SolutionDir)..\path\to\Math`

You'll see the use of the macros a lot when it comes to C++ and other Visual Studio projects not just for include directories, but for build events as well.

Once you've added a list of include directories, you can go back to including your headers in the source code as normal:

`#include "math.h"`

In the event you need to use a relative path from one of your included folders, you can do that as well.

```
// some directory inside of Math
#include "MoreMath\moremath.h"
// some directory above Math
#include "..\AboveMath\abovemath.h"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it...

Remove this question if necessary. The problem was that I didn't backtrack the filepath in my `#include "math.h"`. They should instead have said `#include "..\Math\math.h"`.

Comment: I believe you can delete your own question. You probably need to delete your answer first.